# Get sum of data between two tables where date1 is greater than or equal to date2 : Power query

Tags: powerquery

I've a table that has the required quantity and another table with available Instock quantity.

```
I need Sum(Instock Qty) where TBL1.Material = Inventory.Material AND
TBL1.[Ship From] = Inventory.[Ship From] AND
TBL1.[Code date] => Inventory.[Inv Date]
```

Table1
Material    Required Qty    Location    Req Date
4300    50  4095    7/10/2018
4300    40  4095    7/19/2018
4300    108 4095    7/22/2018
4400    50  4095    7/15/2018
4500    60  4095    7/31/2018

Inventory
Material    Instock Qty Inv Loc Inv Date
4300    20  4095    6/16/2018
4300    100 4095    6/17/2018
4300    30  4095    6/16/2018
4400    40  4095    8/2/2018
4500    30  4095    6/16/2018
4500    20  4095    6/16/2018

For every Material, Ship From, we need Sum(quantity) check whether next item has enough quantity to fulfill shipment.

Required Output
Material    Required Qty    Location    Req Date    Sum Qty Rem Qty Can we Fulfill  Notes
4300    50  4095    7/10/2018   150 100 YES Check whether Item, Ship from match, get sum(qty) for Req Date greater than Inv Date
4300    40  4095    7/19/2018   100 60  YES For the same item as Row1, get remaining quanitity and check whether req qty is less than rem qty
4300    108 4095    7/22/2018   60  -48 NO  For the same item as Row2, get remaining quanitity and check whether req qty is less than rem qty
4400    50  4095    7/15/2018   Not Available   Not Available   NO  Cannot fulfill as we do not have enough Instock Qty for Item = 4400, Ship From = 4095 & Req Date is less than Inv Date
4500    60  4095    7/31/2018   50  -10 NO  Req date is greater than Inv Date but we do not have enough quantity to fulfill shipment

Sorry as I do not know how to format tables on SO questions.
I tried but it didn't format it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you can do, but in general you want to first filter out rows where Code Date is before Inv Date, and then group by the Material and Ship From columns.

Here is one approach that only uses the UI:

1. Click on the Code Date column and then, while holding control, click on the  Inv Date column. Go to the Add Column ribbon, click on the arrow in the Date drop button, and choose "Subtract days"
2. In the new column, click on the button with the arrow, then go to Number Filters and choose "Greater Than or Equal To..."
3. In the filter builder, set the second combobox in the first row to "0", so that it reads "is greater than or equal to" and "0". Click OK.
4. Select both the Material and Ship From columns (using click/control click as mentioned before). Right click on them and choose "Group By...".
5. In the builder, choose the Sum Operation, and choose Instock Qty as the column. Choose the new column name to be something more accurate.

In the Advanced Editor the code should look like:

`let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Inserted Date Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Subtraction", each Duration.Days([Code date] - [Inv Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Inserted Date Subtraction", each [Subtraction] >= 0),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Material", "Ship From"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Instock Qty]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"`

Comment: This should be easier in sql right? Can you help in building a query, right now my brain isn't working. I've been up since 4 AM.